# Get main file name from inside a library function

Tags: python

Suppose I have 2 files `A.py` and `B.py`. They both do

```
import C
print(C.get_my_name())
```

and in the lib file C.py

```
def get_my_name():
    ????
```

Is there a way to define the `get_my_name` function such that when `A.py` is run, the result is 'A.py' and when `B.py` is run, the result is 'B.py'?

Comment: I think something like https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html might help.  Just return the traceback's filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest a different approach that is not reliant on browsing through source code:

```
import sys, ntpath

def get_my_name():
    return ntpath.basename(sys.argv[0])
```

`sys.argv[0]` contains path of the script running, so we can just extract basename from that and there's our name.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this kinda thing before; but I'm not sure if this is what you want:

In C.py

```
import os
import traceback

def get_name():
    tb = traceback.extract_stack()
    return os.path.basename(tb[0].filename)
```

In A.py

```
import C

print(C.get_name())
```

in B.py

```
import C

print(C.get_name())
```

Addendum: the get_name() returns the first item in the stack.